# Spring Cloud Stream POJO from/to JSON Exceptions

Tags: java, jackson, rabbitmq, messaging, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream.

- Inside the project, i only want to handle **Java objects**
- For MQ (rabbit), i want the Payload of message could be converted to **JSON format** automatically from java objects (which is flexible in future).

But when run the application, exception is thrown...

---

So output channel configuration is:

```
    output:
      destination: response
      contentType: application/json
```

And output and model code is like:

```
    /** Source method*/
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(outputChannel=Sink.OUTPUT)
    public MessageSource<String> timerReportMessageSource() {
        return new MessageSource<String>() {
            public Message<String> receive() {
                Response response = new Response(1, "response1");
                return new GenericMessage(response);
            }
        };
    }

    /** Model class */
    public class Response implements Serializable{
        public long id;
        public String name;
    }
```

Exception information:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'output'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: payload must not be null
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:449) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:70) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:64) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:171) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$400(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:45) ~[spring-integration-amqp-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$1.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:95) ~[spring-integration-amqp-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:777) ~[spring-rabbit-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: payload must not be null
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.support.MutableMessage.<init>(MutableMessage.java:57) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.support.MutableMessage.<init>(MutableMessage.java:53) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.support.MutableMessageBuilder.withPayload(MutableMessageBuilder.java:86) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.support.MutableMessageBuilderFactory.withPayload(MutableMessageBuilderFactory.java:35) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.support.MutableMessageBuilderFactory.withPayload(MutableMessageBuilderFactory.java:26) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$ContentTypeConvertingInterceptor.preSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:194) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.1.0.M1.jar:1.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:538) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:415) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
```

So my question is:

- Did i **miss** something (configuration...) if i want to **force java object to json** automatically? Really appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like i'm using the wrong annotation, should be `@StreamListerner `insteadof `@ServiceActivator`

Answer (score 0):

The `null` message payload says the message conversion doesn't take place. Based on your configuration, the message conversion should have taken place by the `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`. By any chance, you don't have that in the classpath or having a custom `MessageConverter` that somehow returns `null`?

Comment: Thank you, do you have a sample or guide?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, your outbound message is likely not converted correctly. The generic code is incorrect and there are some unchecked casts in there: Try this instead before moving forward.

`public MessageSource<Response> timerReportMessageSource() {
        return new MessageSource<Response>() {
            public Message<Response> receive() {
                Response response = new Response(1, "response1");
                return new GenericMessage<>(response);
            }
        };
    }`